# OutputCache Filter not working on IIS

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, iis

I have some method in a controller which get information from a mongodb, but the latency between my production server and the server which hosts the mongodb is quite big.

So I decided to cache that information, since its readonly info, it's not likely to change.

In a local enviroment it works neat, however, when I deploy to production, its not caching at all, it takes a lot of time everytime I hit the page.

This is how I implemented cache:

```
[OutputCacheProfile(CacheProfile="HourCache", VaryByParam="None", Location="OutputCacheLocation.Server")]
public ActionResult Method()
{
   ... here get info from mongodb
}
```

So, I don't really know if there is something I have to configure in IIS to make it work.

PD: IIS 8

Comment: May be your app pool is getting recycled frequently in production? The cache is lost whenever app pool recycles.

Comment: Did you also try just [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "None")]. If that works, then the error is in reading the profile information from web.config?